# skipping spaces in C using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, trim, c-strings, function-definition

I've been asked to do this:

> Make a `skip_spaces()` function accepting a string `s`, that returns a reference to the first element in the array that is not a space character (if the string is only composed of spaces, the pointer will address the null terminator `\0`).
> Then make a main program principal calling this function with a string read on `stdin`.
> From the given result, the program will then display the string from the first non-space `char`."

I've only started using pointers, and I'm clearly not a C expert, so I'm pretty lost here.
Here is what I got so far:

In `skip_spaces.c` I have:

```
char *skip_spaces(char *s[]) {
  char *ref = '\0';
  int i = 0;
  while (*s[i] != '\0') {
    if (*s[i] == ' '):
      i++;
    else {
      *ref = *s[i];
    }
  }
}
```

In `skip_spaces.h` I have:

```
char *skip_spaces(char *);
```

And my main program:

```
#include "skip_spaces.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int input;
    char *str[30];
    char *spaceless;
    printf("input string : ");
    input = scanf("%s", str);
    if (input == 1) {
        int i = 0;
        spaceless = skip_spaces(str);
        printf("modified string : %s.", spaceless);
    return -1;
}
```

Now, I'm not sure yet if the program even does what I want it to do.

My issue here is that I can't even test it out at this point: I've tried a loooot of stuff, I can never compile properly, whenever I fix an issue somewhere, I get another issue else where. Pretty much all errors come from my main program.

I have two very persistent errors:

- `error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’`

This error points at my input = scanf line, more precisely to my str var

- `skip_spaces.h:1:8: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’`

I've tried fidgetting, placing `*` here and `&` there, but either I have these 2 errors, either I have a lot more others...

I've even found several working codes for this exact function on the Internet (most were from SO actually), but whenever I try to implement their working solution in my code, I get these errors again. 100% certain my problem comes from my comprehension of pointers. I hope someone can shed some light.

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). See [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Compile your C code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program. If allowed, install [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your personal laptop

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you for your suggestions! I always forget about using GDB... I'm currently on Windows 10 using the Linux shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration

```
char *str[30];
```

does not make a sense. It declares an array of pointers while you need to declare a character array that will contain a string.

```
char str[30];
```

The conversion specifier used in this call

```
input = scanf("%s", str);
```

skips leading white spaces, so it also does not make a sense because the entered string will not contain leading white spaces. Instead, use the standard function `fgets`.

The parameter of the function `skip_spaces` declared like

```
char* s[]
```

as it was mentioned above is incorrect. You need to pass to the function a string. So the parameter should be declared like

```
const char *s
```

Pay attention to the qualifier `const`. It says the user of the function that the string itself will not be changed within the function.

Within the function `skip_spaces` this declaration

char* ref = '\0';

declares a null pointer. Thus dereferencing it

```
  *ref = *s[i];
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Also, the set of white space does not consist only the one character `' '`. For example, the user can type the tab character `'\t'`.

And the output message

```
printf("modified string : %s.",spaceless);
```

is confusing. The source string is not modified. The function just returns a pointer to the first non-white space character. The string itself stays unchanged.

The function can be declared and defined as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char * skip_spaces( const char *s  )
{
    while ( *s && isspace( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;
    
    return ( char * )s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 30 };
    char str[N];
    
    printf( "Input a string (no more than %d characters): ", N );
    
    if ( fgets( str, N, stdin ) )
    {
        str[ strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
        printf( "The left trimmed string is \"%s\"", skip_spaces( str ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the string `"          Hello World!"` then the program output will look like

```
Input a string (no more than 30 characters):           Hello World!
The left trimmed string is "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and explanations. I'm 100% guilty of not reading the documentation of scanf before using it...

Comment: @froggyalex You could use scanf but the conversion specifier shall be another as for example if ( scanf( "%29[^\n]", str ) == 1 )

Comment: I would suggest using `%29s` or `%29[^\n]` as the `scanf` format speifier in your answer as well to prevent a buffer overflow.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why is preventing a buffer overflow useless?

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang I already pointed in my comment to use for example if ( scanf( "%29[^\n]", str ) == 1 ) . Why are you repeating me?! It seems what you can do is to repeat after others what they write.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow First of all I know that you mentioned it in the comments, otherwise I wouldn't have said "as well". Second of all I set the format specifier to %19s in my answer long before you posted that comment, so I didn't copy anything. And third of all not everyone reads through the comments, so I would still suggest adding it to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Working code

This simple function removes leading spaces from a string:

```
/* remove leading spaces from string */
void rmspaces(char **str)
{
    while (**str == ' ')
        (*str)++;
}
```

It can be called like this:

```
char *str = "  hello";
rmspaces(&str);
```

### Explanation

Your approach it to create a whole new string without the leading spaces, but it's way simpler to pass a pointer to the pointer that points to the first character of the string. Then you can just move the pointer `*str` to the next character using `(*str)++;` while the character is a space.

This has the advantage that no new string has to be allocated every time the function is called, because the old string can be *reused*.

There is also no need to check if the current character is the terminating [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) `'\0'`, because that is automatically assured by the condition in the while-loop.

```
/* sufficient */
while (**str == ' ')

/* unnecessary */
while (**str != '\0' && **str == ' ')
```

### User input

If you scan for user input using `scanf`, leading whitespaces will automatically be removed as mentioned in [Vlad from Moscow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66954923/14947044).

```
char str[20];
/*
 * prevent buffer overflow and
 * take null character into account 
 */
scanf("%19s");
```

If you don't want `scanf` to automatically trim leading whitespaces, you could use `fgets`. That may be helpful if you only want to trim simple spaces `' '` using the function `void rmspaces(char **str)`.

```
char str[20];
/* prevent buffer overflow */
fgets(str, 20, stdin);
```

### Whitespace vs. space

There is a difference between whitespaces and spaces. A whitespace could be something like a tab `'\t'` or a newline `'\n'`, while a space can only be `' '`.

This is how you check if a character is a whitespace:

```
/* `c` is an `unsigned char` */
if (isspace(c))
```

This is how you check if a character is a space:

```
/* `c` is an `unsigned char` */
if (c == ' ')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate having an explanation to your code suggestion. However ... pointers of pointers? Jeez... Now I'm even more confused lol

Comment: @Andy Sukowski-Bang Why do you have copied and pasted in fact parts of my answer? This is not a good behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I didn't *copy paste* parts of your answer. The only think I added after you mentioned it in your answer is the fact that `scanf` automatically removes leading whitespaces, but I expanded on that point and added code for preventing buffer overflow etc. But I have now referenced your answer in my post and added a link to it.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang In my answer there is very clear written that the set of white spaces does  not consist from one character ' '. So your comment to my answer did not make any sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well then I must have overlooked that line. Anyway I didn't copy that aspect. And concerning the automatic removal of whitespaces when using `scanf`, I've already given you credit by inserting a link to your answer (as I said).

Comment: @froggyalex The pointer to the pointer is only necessary to pass the address of `*str` to the method `rmspaces`. And while it might look a bit scary at first, it's the most elegant way to trim leading spaces in my opinion.

Comment: An alternative (simpler?) interface to `rmspaces()` would be `char *rmspaces(char *str)`.  then you don't need the double pointer notation: `char *rmspaces(char *str) { while (*str == ' ') str++; return str; }` would do the job.  This will stop on the null terminator or any other character that isn't a blank.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are right, that might be easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

C already provides a function that can do that for you. The `strspn(const char *s, const char *accept)` function will return the initial number of characters in `s` made up of characters in the `accept` string. See [man 3 strspn](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html)

If you use `" \t\n"` (for `space`, `tab`, `newline`) for `accept` then the function returns the number of leading whitespace characters in the string `s`. If `s` is all whitespace, it returns the number of characters in `s`.

All you need to do is return `s + strspn (s, " \t\n")` and you have your answer, e.g.

```
const char *skip_spaces (const char *s)
{
    return s + strspn (s, " \t\n");     /* return pointer to 1st non-space or '\0' */
}
```

A full example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *skip_spaces (const char *s)
{
    return s + strspn (s, " \t\n");     /* return pointer to 1st non-space or '\0' */
}

int main (void) {
    
    const char *str[] = { "     w/leading space",
                          "w/o leading space",
                          "         \t  " };
    size_t n = sizeof str/sizeof *str;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!*skip_spaces (str[i]))
            printf ("skip_spaces (str[%zu]): '%s' (all spaces)\n", 
                    i, skip_spaces (str[i]));
        else
            printf ("skip_spaces (str[%zu]): '%s'\n", i, skip_spaces (str[i]));
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/skip_spaces
skip_spaces (str[0]): 'w/leading space'
skip_spaces (str[1]): 'w/o leading space'
skip_spaces (str[2]): '' (all spaces)
```

There is always more than one way to *skin-the-cat* in C `:)`

Also when visiting the man page, note the companion function `strcspn (const char *s, const char *reject)` does just the opposite, returning the initial number of characters in `s` NOT containing any of the characters in `reject`. (quite useful for trimming the `'\n'` at the end of buffers filled by `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`).